# Using elisp symbol to implement call-by-reference, but can not get value from `symbol-value`

Tags: emacs, lisp, symbols

Emacs-lisp is default using [call-by-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value), but I'm trying use its symbol mechanism to simulate [call-by-reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference).

For example,

```
(setq lexical-binding nil)

(defun cbr (x)
  (message "cbr (symbol-name x) %s" (symbol-name x))
  (message "cbr (symbol-value x) %s" (symbol-value x))
  (set x 2))

(let ((a 1))
  (cbr 'a)
  a)
;; cbr (symbol-name x) a
;; cbr (symbol-value x) 1
;; 2
```

It works well, because the result of `let` expression is 2, so it is indeed the call-by-reference behavior.

However, if I change the name from `a` to `x`:

```
(let ((x 1))
  (cbr 'x)
  x)
;; cbr (symbol-name x) x
;; cbr (symbol-value x) x
;; 1
```

Now it doesn't work as expected anymore.

Why?

Notice that it even can not get the correct `symbol-name` in `cbr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have known what happen.

The second program returns 1, because the symbol `x` is captured by `cbr`'s param `x`. When the body of  `cbr` is evaluated, there are two bindings in the environment: one is the let binding `x = 1`, the other is `x = x` which is created by `cbr`'s application. The symbol `x` in the `(set x 2)` uses the later one.

A workaround of this question is:

```
(let ((gen-x (gensym)))
  (set gen-x 1)
  (cbr gen-x)
  (symbol-value gen-x))
;; cbr (symbol-name x) g36
;; cbr (symbol-value x) 1
;; 2
```

Answer (score 1):

What should be clear from this is that relying on dynamic scope and `symbol-value` is a disaster: you need gensyms all over the place.  Relying on dynamic scope for anything is generally a disaster, *except* in the specific, rare but extremely useful, case where you actually want dynamic scope.

But solving this problem trivial, even in elisp, with lexical scope.  Here is one simple approach:

```lisp
(defmacro ref (form)
  ;; Construct a reference to a form
  (unless lexical-binding
    (error "doomed"))
  (let ((<setting> (gensym)))
    `(lambda (&rest ,<setting>)          ;hack for &optional (v nil vp)
       (cond
        ((null ,<setting>)
         ,form)
        ((null (cdr ,<setting>))
         (setf ,form (car ,<setting>)))
        (t
         (error "mutant"))))))

(defun ref-value (ref)
  (funcall ref))

(defun set-ref-value (ref value)
  ;; should be (setf ref-value), but elisp
  (funcall ref value))
```

And now, for instance, given:

```lisp
(defun outer (v)
  (let ((x 1))
    (princ (format "x is first %s\n" x))
    (inner (ref x) v)
    (princ (format "and x is now %s\n" x))
    x))

(defun inner (ref v)
  (princ (format " ref is first %s\n" (ref-value ref)))
  (set-ref-value ref v)
  (princ (format " and ref is now %s\n" (ref-value ref))))
```

Then

```lisp
ELISP> (outer 4)
x is first 1
 ref is first 1
 and ref is now 4
and x is now 4

4 (#o4, #x4, ?\C-d)
```